# UIWebView delegate Methods

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, delegates

After the UIWebView catchs an error through didLoadWithErrors, how do I then get it to retry and rerun through its delegate methods.

I tried using

```
[webView reload]
```

However it does no rerun through the delegate methods and so I do not know weather the reload has been successful or not.

Can anyone tell me how to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reload method reloads the current page - if there is no page, because you haven't successfully loaded one, there is nothing to reload.

You can "reload" the page as you meant by sending the last request again with the -loadRequest: message.
If the UIWebView fails again you should log the localized description of the error (to check whether there is e.g. no connection or a problem in your app) and send a UIAlertView to inform the user about the error.

And my advice: For a better user interface just tell the error details if you think the user will understand them (like "No Connection to the internet") but don't send cryptic messages like "Unknown Error 2525:Wfo3" - instead just tell the user that an error occurred.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Currently when didLoadWithError is caught, if the error is related to no internet connection, I place a refresh button the page. I tried what you said and attempt to resend the load request when they click refresh, however I then get the error Failed to load webpage with error: Frame load interrupted. I was expecting it to detect there was still no internet connection, and  continue to show the refresh button.

Comment: Could you please tell me which URL you tried to open ? Please copy the exact url from you code.

Comment: opps its okay now :), Thanks for your help I spent ages trying to work out how to get the UIWebView to rerun through the delegate methods! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem ;)
But to complete that thread: The "Frame load interrupted" error often occurs because you didn't tell the UIWebView of what kind a document is. For example if you asked for opening www.google.com instead of http://www.google.com/

Comment: ah thats exactly what I did as well google.com, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Oh...StackOverflow converted my link. The difference beetween the first and the second google-URL was that the second started with http://